# HTTP GET Jwt Request work with postman but same with axios return 401 Unauthorized

Tags: vue.js, http, https, axios, jwt

I have a request against an enpoint that need a token
With postman request work fine and answere 200 and looks like that:

[image]

Axios has previously done a succesfull login request that gave it to have a valid token
In the login callback methode I allowed axios to produce request with a valid jwt token:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
```

Then axios do a call is done by this line:

```
axios.get("https://localhost:44336/api/CurrentBet")
```

But it produces 2 requests: one with answer 204 No Content and another one with answer 401 Unauthorized

the first request is:

[image]

the second request is :

[image]

Do you have any idea about what happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: You see how your postman request uses `Bearer` I think you need to say `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = \`Bearer ${token}\``.

Comment: @camwhite your answer is exact, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jwt , axios should be set with code bellow;

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```